# Trying to read certain text from a file that has strange characters. (Python)

Tags: python, file, encoding, io, character

Hello I'm trying to grab data from a keyword in a text document as a project, I am able to do this using this code. I am very new to python and im not sure where to start to troubleshoot this issue.

```
data_file = open("test.txt", "r")

Keyword = raw_input("Please enter the keyword: ")

go = False

start = Keyword
end = "[+][+]"

with open("test.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if start in line: go = True
        elif end in line:
            go = False
            continue
        if go:
            print(line)
```

This code works great for a sample text document like

```
Something Something Something Something   
Something Something Something Something  
Something Keyword:  
 Data  
 Data  
 Data  
 Data  
End  
 Something
```

However i run into an issue when trying to read from a file that has strange characters. for example:

```
2015/08/14 15:48:30 OUT:
2015/08/14 15:48:30 OUT:
 PQ=
(3<   ’’aÈ©ÿY˜ü   â     [+][+]52

2015/08/14 15:48:31:IN[+]53[+][+]101[+]-1[+] **Keyword** ,SHOWALL
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
end
```

Since the goal is to read from this text document and just print out the words in between the Keyword and End. it will not execute if it has these characters in them. and for the project I can not remove these characters it just has to be able to read through the document and find the keyword and print out whats in between.

Any ideas on how i can read from a text document that has these strange characters with it processing it correctly rather than just crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to open the file in binary mode. You could then use a regular expression to extract all the text between your entered keyword and "end". Whole words could then be extracted using another regular expression:

```
import re

with open("input.txt", "rb") as f_input:     
    start_token = raw_input("Please enter the start keyword: ")
    end_token = raw_input("Please enter the end keyword: ")
    reText = re.search("%s(.*?)%s" % (re.escape(start_token), re.escape(end_token)), f_input.read(), re.S)

    if reText:
        for word in re.findall(r"\b\w+\b", reText.group(1)):
            print word
    else:
        print "not found"
```

For your example text this would display:

```
SHOWALL
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
```

Or if you just want all of the text between the two points, `print reText.group(1)` instead of the `for` loop.

**Updated:** added support for a variable end token.

Comment: I seem to be getting closer I have a question about "%s(.*?)end" what if i want to have an input for the end keyword as well? for example rather than having a hard end as the keyword what if i want to read until it reach bananas and have the user input the end keyword.

and on a side note how can i make it so it print the data line by line rather than word by word. Currently it will print out the data in this format 
      
d    
a  
t  
a  
    
rather than 

data

Comment: I have updated the script to allow both to be entered.

Comment: As mentioned, in the text, if you replace the `for` loop with `print reText.group(1)` you will get all of the text in the original format.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! I will set this as best answer thanks again! If you dont mind me asking what are some great resources to continue learning File I/O in Python?

Comment: Glad it worked. Dive into Python is a good free book to start learning about most things. Also check out the Python CSV library which is very handy. Learning regular expressions will take time but very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The file contains binary content so it should be opened in binary mode

You can do this by doing

```
data_file = open("test.txt", "rb")
```

Comment: hmm it still isnt reading from the read for example this is a preview of the file I want to get data from it but due to the binary code inbetween it doesnt fully read the file.   
  
2015/08/14 15:48:30 OUT:ACK 1
2015/08/14 15:48:30 OUT:ACK 10376
 PQ=
(3<   ’’aÈ©ÿY˜ü   â     [+][+]52

2015/08/14 15:48:31:IN[+]53[+][+]101[+]-1[+]**Keyword**,SHOWALL
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
**data**
end